# Missing Server and User in Credentials

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm currently working with VS'13 for making c# metro forms and mysql workbench for database. The problem occurring is that it shows the error of

> Missing Server and User in Credentials.
>   Host 'WAJiHA' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

(as you can see in the picture as well).

DataAccess file has following settings 
"Server=localhost;Database=sbhd_v13;Uid=root;password=test123";

The database is connected with the project and executes query but doesnot allows to access the connection to the current project or any other project. 
It was working good last night idk which configurations i had edited by mistake which is causing such error. 
Kindly help me! I'm unable to find the right solution for this problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNfaY.jpg)

Comment: uuhhmmm maybe with the `;` `password=test123";` try `password=test123;"`

Comment: Nope this still gives the same error..

Answer (score 1):

Change your posted connection string to be like

```
string myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=test123;database=sbhd_v13;";
```

Comment: What could be the problem that im getting this  
"Missing Server and User in Credentials.

Host 'WAJiHA' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"